# What type of antenna is this?

Tags: antenna

I was hiking in the mountains when I stumbled upon this antenna. I had no connection throughout the mountain until I reached this antenna. I noticed that it said on the metal. "Alarm Actuated Public Safety Equipment". I was curious if anyone knew why this would arbitrarily be on a random mountain.[image]

Comment: The three parallel element on the right is a Yagi-Uda wire antenna

Comment: I count at least three antennas in this picture; which one?

Comment: **Why** it would be on a mountain? I'd guess it would be public safety equipment. Why isn't it on other mountains?

Comment: @MarcusMüller - All of them. It seems weird that they are there.

Comment: @Neil_UK not sure. The mountain I was on is in California.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Or four if you count the rather large optical-band antenna facing roughly south...

Comment: @BrianDrummond that optical-band antenna contains a mixer to baseband, does it still count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems weird that they are there.

Um, no?

I see environmental sensors on that mast, and that data has to go somewhere.

Let's look into this: the large stick sticking out top is a monopole or a dipole hidden inside a plastic tubing. Since I'm missing any size reference, it's hard to tell which frequencies this is designed to operate on, but seeing it's omnidirectional, this is either to broadcast something low-rate in all directions (maybe emergency warnings, maybe firefighter comms, maybe commercial aviation comms?); maybe it's used as receiving antenna from all directions.

The three parallel verticals sticking out right make a Yagi-Uda. With three elements, it *is* a directive antenna, but not *very* directive. This might be to illuminate a valley or hill nearby. Again, hard to tell the frequencies without a size reference. If you remember how long these elements were: the wavelength of the frequency it's used for is roughly twice as long.

The third antenna is the plastic square looking out front. When you look at it, there's actually a pair of coax going into it, making me believe this is a dual-polarization microwave antenna. This is most probably a relatively high-rate point-to-point link – maybe relaying data through another mast on another hill, or bringing internet to a single building, or simply being backhaul for cellular infrastructure.

None of this strikes me as unusual – whenever I was in California, there were a lot of wireless infrastructure all over the place. In hilly areas, you need to have a couple of masts, otherwise you'll end up without any service coverage – and that might be something catastrophe protection agencies are averse to.

Comment: Thank you so much for this information. I am still in college - so I might not know everything, but I am trying to learn as much as I can. My specialization in electrical engineering is going to be in microwave and antenna engineering. I am in my junior year. Sorry, for the basic question.

Comment: @GenoC don't be sorry – it's good to ask! Especially in antenna design, it's very usual that things looks strange at first, and only through quite some theory mixed with real-world experience and simulation do a lot of them make sense.

Comment: There is a size reference. Solar cells are normally either 5 or 6 inches across, so the vertical dimension of the solar panel is either 20 or 24 inches (50 or 60cm) plus change. That puts the Yagi elements in  the same ballpark, for 1m wavelength or a little more, or just below 300MHz.

Answer (score 3):

The white box antenna in the middle is a multi-band cellular crossed-pol antenna, probably used by a cell phone modem. [X-POL-2-5G](https://poynting.tech/antennas/xpol-2-5g/). Note the twin coaxial cable leading from the antenna, for MIMO.
[image: X-POL-2-5G]

The small conical thing on the right is a GPS antenna - something like [this one](https://www.pctel.com/antenna-product/gnss-time-sync-high-gain-high-rejection-antenna/) from PCTEL?
[image]

The centre rod could be a collinear antenna in a fibreglass radome, or just a lightning conductor, the way it runs continuously down to the bottom of the photo.

The Yagi on the right is for VHF, perhaps the high end of the "high band", say 170 MHz, it's hard to get the scale right. Elements are removeable for transport so it's fairly big.

The left hand stalk holds an [ultrasonic anemometer](https://www.google.com/search?q=ultrasonic%20anemometer&tbm=isch) / wind direction sensor, possibly combined with other weather instruments.

I can't speculate on its purpose, but it looks like the owner has built just one or two of these towers, not 10 or 20.

Comment: Thank you for this information. We get a lot of fires in that specific area from time to time. Seems like they are monitoring weather, conditions, etc.

Comment: If the center rod is not a lightning conductor, it could also be a vertical 1/2-wave symmetrical dipole (center mounted) or a 5/8-wave J-pole antenna for 27 MHz or some such.